# Text draws out of CellBounds during CellPainting

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual-studio-addins

I'm overriding the CellPainting event for a DataGridView in an AddIn for VSTS2010. Basically I have 2 lines of data and I want the first line to be black and the second line to be grey. That all works just fine, but sometimes, and for no reason I can tell, occasionally the cell contents will be painted about 50 pixels to the left and 5 pixels up from where it should be.
For example:
[image: Example]

The hightlighted filename is ExecutionHints.cs but all you can see is "nHints.cs"

This happens say in just 1 VSTS session of 3, or sometimes just at some point during the afternoon for 1 session. There appears to be no pattern for when it happens.

I've tried using e.CellBounds.X and even hardcoding "2" as the X position for the DrawString but it still happens. I've attached a debugger when it happens and the values are correct, i.e. Value == "ExecutionHints.cs", e.CellBounds.X == 1, e.ClipBounds.X == 0.

Any ideas? Suggestions to try?

Code:

```
private void grdFiles_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (grdFiles.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name != clmDisplay.Name || e.RowIndex < 0) return;

    var lines = new string[] { "", "" };
    SolidBrush backColorBrush;

    var selected = (DataGridViewElementStates.Selected & e.State) == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected;

    // Get back colour depending on cell contents.
    if (e.Value != null)
    {
        lines = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(e.Value.ToString(), Environment.NewLine);
        backColorBrush = selected ? new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor) : GetBackBrushColor(lines[1]);
    }
    else
        backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(selected ? e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor : e.CellStyle.BackColor);

    using (Brush gridBrush = new SolidBrush(this.grdFiles.GridColor))
    {
        using (Pen gridLinePen = new Pen(gridBrush))
        {
            // Erase the cell.
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds);

            // Draw the grid lines (only the right and bottom lines; 
            // DataGridView takes care of the others).
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Left,
                e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, e.CellBounds.Right - 1,
                e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Right - 1,
                e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Right - 1,
                e.CellBounds.Bottom);

            // Draw the text content of the cell, ignoring alignment. 
            if (e.Value != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(lines[0], e.CellStyle.Font, Brushes.Black,  2, e.CellBounds.Y + 2, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(lines[1], e.CellStyle.Font, selected ? Brushes.White : Brushes.Gray, 2, e.CellBounds.Y + 18, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    backColorBrush.Dispose();
}
```